# Find the limit of $u_n = \frac{1\times3\times5\times7\times..........\times(2n-1)}{2\times4\times6\times8\times........\times(2n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

To prove that $u_n = \frac{1\times3\times5\times7\times..........\times(2n-1)}{2\times4\times6\times8\times........\times(2n)}$ converges, we can notice that $1/2$ is the smallest term in the product and $(\frac{2n-1}{2n})$ is the greatest.

Hence : $(1/2)^{2n-1} \leq u_n \leq (\frac{2n-1}{2n})^{2n-1}$.  By squeeze theorem we see that $\lim u_n = 0$.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: $lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{2n-1}{2n})^{2n-1}=\frac{1}{e}$ and not zero, so your solution is incorrect.

Comment: @boaz How can I do it then?

Comment: $u_n=\frac{1\times 2\times\dots\times(2n-1)\times(2n)}{(2\times 4\times\dots\times (2n))^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}\cdot(n!)^2}$. Then use Stirling's approximation of the factorial expresions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint (corrected): Note that
$$
\frac{(1)(3)(5)\ldots(2n-1)}
{(2)(4)(6)\ldots(2n)}=
\frac{(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)\ldots(2n-1)(2n)}
{[(2)(4)(6)\ldots(2n)]^2}=
\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}
=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{4^n}
$$
Now use the estimate
$$
\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}
$$
see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Comment: Wow. Thank you.

Comment: Ok wow, this looked like a cute problem from first sight tho.

Comment: Shouldn't we have $$\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}?$$

Comment: Yes, you right. I fixed it. Thanks 
@Aaron Hendrickson.